# Does adb setprop require a reboot for the changes to take place?

Tags: java, android, adb

I have not gotten my device rooted yet, but I was wondering if the command `setprop <key> <value>` required a reboot for the changes to take place. In the past I have edited the `build.prop` file, but the the device required a reboot for the changes to take effect.

I need to change the build information (`ro.build.id`,`ro.build.version`...etc) and have them be reflected in the system properties *instantly*. The System Properties gets its information from the `build.prop` file upon a boot, therefore any changes to the `build.prop` file are not reflected until a reboot.

Does `setprop` change the `build.prop` file, or does it actually change the *current* property of the system, and if so, will this change be reflected *without* a reboot? This is aim of the project. Any help is appreciated.

As a corollary, if the system properties are loaded from the `build.prop` file upon boot, where are these properties *actually* stored?